# UITableView set checkbox state from database values

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, checkbox

I am storing checkbox values (true/false) in database. I want to set checkbox checked/unchecked depending on the values stored in database. how to do that ? my code is,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.frame=CGRectMake(75.0, 50.0, 150.0, 20.0);
    cell.textLabel.text=[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Checked arr size %i",[checkedArr count]);
    BOOL checked =  [[checkedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_bg.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    return cell;


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL checked = [[checkedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    [checkedArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [checkedArr insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_bg.png"];
    cell.accessoryView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
    NSLog(@"Val is %i",val);
    NSLog(@"selected is %@",[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

}
```

I am storing those values in database using an array checkedArr.

```
[dbObj insertQuestData:Question answers:listArray checkVal:checkedArr];
```

here dbObj is database object, others are values that i am storing to database.
Please let me know how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

The list array and checked array should be mutable array sent to database function which fills up the data.

```
    self.listArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.checkedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [dbObj insertQuestData:Question answers:self.listArray checkVal:self.checkedArray];
//    [self insertList:self.listArray andChecks:self.checkedArray];
```

The insertQuestData methods should fill up data like this -

```
- (void) insertList:(NSMutableArray *)list andChecks:(NSMutableArray *)checks
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [list addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %d", i]];
        BOOL checkValue = (i % 4) == 0 ? YES : NO;
        [checks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checkValue]];
    }
}
```

The table datasource methods should be like this - (notice the commented line as correction to your code)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.listArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
//        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
//    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];
//    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//    cell.textLabel.frame=CGRectMake(75.0, 50.0, 150.0, 20.0);
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Checked arr size %i",[self.checkedArray count]);
    BOOL checked =  [[self.checkedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (!checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_bg.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    return cell;    
}
```

This is what my sample code show on iPhone - [every 4th row is (green)ticked/selected and others are grey/unselected]

[image]

Feel free to ask if you have any specific questions / issues you face.

Comment: how to set those values to checkbox, so that checkbox will be remain checked/unchecked depending on value from database(true/false). So that when I move from one view to another and back those checkboxes will retain their state ?

Comment: cell.accessoryView show the checkbox images (tick / white). (Check last 3 lines). As long as your self.checkedArray (data that drives checkbox state), you should be good. Remember, whenever there is any update in data, you should refresh the table using `[tableview reloadData]`.

Comment: thanks a lot. thats working with me. but then even how to set checkbox  depending on bool? and where to place that code ? in cellForRowAtIndexPath or in didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: In _general_, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should be the only place which should layout the cell view. Any action that requires change in the layout, you should change the data source there (self.checkedArray) and then call `[self.tableview reloadData]` or selectively refresh some cells using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` (see developer docs here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: